# Why didn't Japan call for the ICJ to settle the dispute over the Senkaku/Diaoyu Islands?

Tags: international-relations, china, geopolitics, japan, international-court-of-justice

Why didn't Japan call for the ICJ to settle the [dispute over the Senkaku/Diaoyu Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senkaku_Islands_dispute)? I am asking this question, because Japan took its ongoing dispute with South Korea over the Dokdo islands to the ICJ, so I am wondering why Japan didn't do it in this particular case. Wouldn't a call for arbitration put China on the defensive in the same way it has put Korea over the Dokdo island matter?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

China is unlikely to listen to an ICJ ruling, so it carries risk for Japan if China wins and no gain if Japan wins.

From the [Spratlys](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/jul/13/china-damns-international-court-after-south-china-sea-slapdown), where the Phillipines brought the case, **to the ICJ** (aka Hague Tribunal) in 2016, and won against China:

> Beijing has criticised an international court’s stinging rejection of its territorial claims in the South China Sea, with Communist party-controlled newspapers warning of a military escalation in response to what they denounced as a US ploy to thwart China’s rise.

Regarding the details of this case, see [Philippines v. China @ wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippines_v._China).

Just look at the situation in the Spratlys 5 years later.  China has doubled down instead.

On the other hand, South Korea is more likely to act in good faith.

Note that this is **not** something Japan would cite as a reason, as it shows weakness.

**Edit:  please see comments by xngtng below, who raises some valid points re. this answer.**

Comment: I don't know why this answer, with some glaring factual errors, is so much more upvoted than the other one. The case may be relevant but is incomparable. First, the Philippines never took the case to ICJ. It was brought under UNCLOS to the Permanent Court of Arbitration. Beijing claimed PCA has no jurisdiction due to Chinese reservation regarding sovereignty issues when it signed UNCLOS, a reservation which the Philippines recognized.

Comment: UNCLOS does not concern itself with and PCA has therefore no jurisdiction over territorial disputes. Scarborough Shoal that was under arbitration was claimed by the Philippines to be a "rock", which carries no sovereignty claims as far as PCA was concerned, but for Chinese it is an "island" which makes it an issue of territorial sovereignty (see the Arbitration Award on jurisdiction). The crucial difference is that Dokdo/Liancourt, like Senkaku/Diaoyu, are recognized by both sides as islands, making the issue firmly one about sovereignty.

Comment: @xngtng interesting.  You seem to be right about UNCLOS, but [Phillipines **was** the plaintiff apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippines_v._China).  In any case, it seems pretty clear China will just ignore whatever the court says that it doesn't agree with, which is what my answer is about.  Regarding legal specifics, I have a hard time believing you know more than the court does: *On 29 October 2015, the arbitral tribunal ruled that it has jurisdiction over the case,[9] taking up seven of the 15 submissions made by the Philippines*.

Comment: At the end of the day it boils down to:  Philippines won case, China ignored ruling.

Comment: It is one thing if China ignores a court ruling in a process that it has recognized and participated in, it is another thing if it ignores a process altogether. I don't find their position particularly unreasonable (on the issue of the jurisdiction of PCA). South Korea never accepted and is very unlikely to accept an ICJ arbitration neither.

Comment: But unlike actions under UNCLOS where a dispute can be opened by one party, ICJ does not have the power under the currently prevalent interpretation of international law to arbitrate on territorial disputes without both parties' consent. So as far as Japan is concerned, there's no difference between China/Korea on this. China would just refuse the arbitration and the court cannot be involved at all, instead of ignoring the court's ruling afterwards. That's why I find your answer not really making sense for Japan, unlike the other answer.

Comment: Regarding the jurisdiction issue, you'll find that my claims are exactly the same as discussed in PCA's arbitration award on jurisdiction and admissibility (e.g. paragraph 8). Note that I never claimed China was completely right on this. But it was the position they took and I don't find the position to be wholly unreasonable, even if they were wrong.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean there, China would have to agree to ICJ, whereas it didn't have to for UNCLOS.  Not going to edit the answer right now, but you've raised some good point.  To be honest, I remembered the Philippines Spratley case, which I still **do** find relevant, despite your valid clarifications, found this article to back that up and posted it.  I'll see later how this all fits together.

Comment: I do think the SCS case (and general powerlessness of international courts against powerful countries) does form part of the reason for Japan to not even bother if they know China will certainly turn down the offer and they have no reason to agitate on this issue at this time.

Answer (score 19):

This article in the Center for Strategic and International Studies
appear to answer your questions:

> **Japan’s Position**
>
> Japan’s position on the Senkaku Islands is clear. Japan took
> measures to incorporate the islands in January 1895 after having
> carefully surveyed and determined that the islands had been terra
> nullius (no man’s land). Ever since, the Senkaku Islands have been
> under the Japanese administration except for 27 years between 1945
> and 1972 when the islands as part of Okinawa were under the US
> administration but returned to Japan along with Okinawa
> in 1972. Thus, the islands have been under the effective and
> peaceful administration of Japan for more than a century. It is
> clear that the Senkaku Islands are an inherent part of Japan, as
> evidenced by both historical facts and international law, and
> *therefore there is no “dispute” about the sovereign title of the
> islands.*
>
> [Japan Chair Platform: The Senkaku Islands and International Law](https://www.csis.org/analysis/japan-chair-platform-senkaku-islands-and-international-law)

What the article's author thinks China should do

> **China’s Desired Action**
>
> If China considers that their assertion is really good enough to
> beat Japan, what China should do is to bring the matter to the
> ICJ. Since Japan does not consider the Senkaku issue a “dispute”
> there is no reason for Japan to sit and negotiate with China over
> the sovereignty of the islands. *It is the Chinese side that should
> take the initiative to transform the issue into a legal dispute,
> because it is China who is seeking to change the status quo long
> established under international law.*
>
> How could China make it a legal dispute? It is actually quite
> simple. All it has to do is refer the case to ICJ, just like Japan
> has been trying to do with South Korea over the Takeshima Islands
> dispute. If China decided to take this course, Japan would not run
> away from settling the issue at the ICJ.

The author suggests that China is the weaker party and therefore
should take the matter to the ICJ - not Japan, who is the stronger
party and currently exercises control. Unlike the Dokdo/Takeshima
dispute wherein South Korea is the stronger party and Japan the weaker
one.

Disclaimer: the article's author is a Japanese law professor at a
Japanese law school, which might slightly bias his opinion in Japan's
favor.

Comment: So this is a more context rich answer with the same point as Italian Philosophers 4 Monica's answer: Japan has nothing to gain from going to the  ICJ

Comment: Also, asking the ICJ to decide would mean that China has to recognize the authority of the ICJ. Which will go against the Spratley's decision.

Comment: @PeterM.-standsforMonica China has no choice in that as the ICJ is a part of the United Nations (the ICC isn't). If it won't recognize the ICJ, it can be argued that China has no right to the UNSC seat as a permanent member.